# Linq Func argument

Tags: c#, linq, func

I am bit confused what is the meaning of below statements.

```
List<Func<GroupInfoInfo, bool>>()

Groups.Instance.GetGroup(2, grp => TestPredicateGroup(whereCls, grp));

private static bool TestPredicateGroup(List<Func<GroupInfoInfo, bool>> predicates, GroupInfoInfo ri)
{
    foreach (var p in predicates)
    {
        if (!p(ri))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I want to know what is the meaning of `List<Func<GroupInfoInfo, bool>>()` and statement of `if (!p(ri))` in function?

Some confusion in `GetGroup()` lambda expression also.

Comment: [List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) is a `Generic Collection` type in `C#`.

Comment: `predicates` is a List of function who return a boolean value. So it is correct to call them in a `foreach` like that : `!p(ri)`

Answer (score 4):

`List<Func<RoleInfo, bool>>` is a list of functions that take a `RoleInfo` as first and only parameter and returns a `bool`.

`foreach (var p in predicates)` iterates over all the functions (predicates), assigns them to `p` and checks them with `!p(ri)`.

`!p(ri)` actually is a call to a method / delegate (assigned to variable `p`), giving the first argument `ri` which is a `RoleInfo`. The result is negated, so if it returns `false`, the result of the `if` is `true`. In that case, it will return `false`. Else it will go on to the next one and test that until it has checked all predicates. If they all return `true`, the end result of the `TestPredicateGroup` method is `true`.

Comment: p(ri) execute on which field?,I want to ask on id of p.rsid and ri.rsid?

Comment: `p` is just a method `(ri)` is just passing the parameters on the method. `p` won't have a `rsid`, `ri` might.